# If a vector identifies a hyperplane, what does a matrix identify?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ this identifies a hyperplane (through the origin) of equation
$$
w^\top x = 0.
$$
How to generalize this to a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$? What geometrical object can it identify? Presumably something "linear" like a hyperplane but with larger codimension?

#### Possible Idea

My guess is it would identify the following space
$$
\{w\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, Xw = 0\} = \text{nullspace}(X).
$$
Now this is a subspace but what is it geometrically? Does is still look and behave like a hyperplane?

Presumably, each row vector in $X$ essentially identifies a hyperplane. So perhaps it's something like this? Looks like an "envelope" of hyperplanes..

[image]

Comment: The nullspace of a a matrix is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence it has a basis $v_1, \dots, v_k$, and is the span of this basis. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the one dimensional subspaces are the lines through the origin, the two dimensional subspaces are the planes through the origin, the three dimensional subspaces are just $\mathbb{R}^3$. The equation $W^T x = 0$ says that $x$ is orthogonal to all columns of $W$, i.e. the subspace defined by this equation is $range(W)^\perp$.

Comment: Maybe look at the [exterior algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), which can be represented with antisymmetric matrices. In particular, your identification of $x$ with a hyperplane is a way of viewing the [dual space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) as the space of hyperplanes, and then products in it's exterior algebra like $\alpha\wedge\beta$ (which could be identified with an antisymmetric matrix) correspond to the intersection of the hyperplanes represented by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in a way very similar to your first equation.

Comment: To answer your very last question: Geometrically, the nullspace is just the _intersection_ of all the hyperplanes given by the row vectors. Indeed, a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ lies in the nullspace if $x^\top_i w = 0$ for all $i$, which geometrically means that $w$ must lie in every hyperplane. A simple example, the nullspace of a $2\times 3$ matrix $X = [\mathbf{a} \; \mathbf{b}]^\top$ is a 1-dimensional subspace (a line) in \mathbb{R}^3, whose direction is $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix can identify many things.
One example is as you say a subspace which has eigenvalue $0$. In other words the set of vectors $\bf w$ for which $\bf Xw = 0$

Another example is the opposite : a set of vectors which never gives $0$ under matrix-vector multiplication and contains no portion of a vector spanned by the subspace $\bf Xw = 0$. This can be described as a minimum norm problem. Or we can just project away any part of the vector lying in the subspace.

In engineering matrices can represent a lot of different things. We would need whole books to go in depth on it. There is no branch of engineering which linear algebra and matrices haven't reached.

Comment: $\{w \in \Bbb R^n : Xw \neq 0\}$ is not a subspace...

Comment: Find a basis for the subspace. Find a basis for the complementary space. Together they build our whole space.

Comment: Yes, but you can uniquely and readily remove any linear addition that happens to lie in the nullspace for any vector which $Xw \neq 0$. Just a simple projection will do it. We should come up with a different word for it then because it is an extremely useful conceptual division of sets of vectors in engineering.

Comment: Just say "the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $X$", instead of complicating it. There is no unique such thing, but given an inner product (and $\Bbb R^n$ has a natural one: the dot product), there is a unique such complementary subspace.

Comment: However, there are lots of uses for complicating it here. Basically at least one in every branch of engineering.

Comment: I don't know engineering. Usually it's a good idea to say something clearly and concisely, especially if you're helping someone else understand it. Just a pedagogical suggestion.

Comment: The concept of subspace is not helpful. In fact it is the one definition that makes it overly complicated and not my explanation.