# Bounce a vector off multiple hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, physics

Given a unit vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ identifying a hyperplane, it is possible to "bounce" another vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ against this hyperplane as follows
$$
v' = v - 2(v^\top x)x,
$$
e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects). Is there an equivalent of this operation when we have $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ unit vectors identifying $m$ hyperplanes?

Comment: You can apply this operation repeatedly. Do observe that the end result depends on the order of bounces; which hyperplane you bounce from first, which is second etc. For example, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the unit normals to two planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$, with an angle $\theta$ between them, and $s_1,s_2$ are the respective bounces, then both $s_1\circ s_2$ and $s_2\circ s_1$ are rotations by the angle $2\theta$ about the axis formed by the intersection of the two planes. The difference being that one is clockwise and the other counterclockwise. It gets more complicated with more (hyper)planes.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen good point. I did think about applying them in succession, but then (as you mention) this operation depends on the order of bounces and it’s not clear to me which order would be optimal.

Comment: I saw [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497662/if-a-vector-identifies-a-hyperplane-what-does-a-matrix-identify), where you asked for a geometric interpretation of $\mathrm{nullspace}(X)$ in terms of the hyperspaces given by the row vectors of $X$. I interpreted this "bouncing off question" in the spirit of that previous question. However, if you want to find $v'$ for a point object that bounces at several hyperplanes at generic positions, then my answer is not what you want. (And then Jyrki's comment is a more appropriate answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first restate your question.

"Suppose a point object moves towards a linear subspace $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with a velocity vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The point will bounce off this linear subspace at the origin.
The linear subspace is the orthogonal complement of $m$ unit vectors $x_1,\ldots, x_m$, i.e. $U =\mathrm{span}\{ x_1,\ldots, x_m\}^\perp$.  What will the point's velocity vector $v'$ be after the bounce?"

Note:  $U$ is the intersection of the $m$ hyperplanes given by their normal vectors $x_i$. So $\dim U = n-m$ if the $x_i$ are linearly independent.

**The geometric idea.**
After the bounce, the velocity $v'$ is the reflection of $v$ w.r.t. the subspace $U$.
The idea is to decompose the vector $v = v_t + v_n$ into a tangent part $v_t \in U$ and normal part $v_n \in U^\perp = \mathrm{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_m\}$. Then $$v' = v_t - v_n.$$

**The formula.**
We assume that $x_1,\ldots, x_m$ are **orthogonal** unit vectors. (These vectors can be obtained after a Gram-Schmidt method.) Now, $v_n$ is the projection of $v$ onto the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$. Since $\{x_1,\ldots, x_m\}$ form an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
 v_n &= \sum_{i=0}^m (v^T x_i) x_i \\
 v_t &= v- v_t.
\end{align*}
$$
We can rewrite these formulas.
Introduce the $n\times m$ matrix $X= [x_1 \cdots x_m]$. The above expressions then become
$$
\begin{align*}
 v_n &= XX^T v \\
 v_t &= (I - XX^T) v.
\end{align*}
$$
If you are unfamiliar with these formulas, have a look at [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas). The most important thing to know is this: since the $x_i$ are orthonormal, we can write the orthogonal projections onto $U^\perp$ and $U$ as $XX^T$ and $I-XX^T$ respectively.

So we obtain
$$
v' = (I - 2XX^T) v.
$$
If $U$ is a hyperplane with normal $x$, then $X =[x]$ and we get $v' = (I-2xx^T)v$ as before.

Comment: Hold on. If $X$ is orthogonal then $XX^\top = I$ so really $v_t = v = v_n$?

Comment: No, $X$ has orthonormal column vectors, so $X^T X = I$ holds. If $X$ is square, then $X$ is an orthogonal matrix. Simple example to fiddle around with: let $$X = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Calculate $XX^T$ and $X^T X$ and see what you get. $XX^T$ is the projection onto the $xy$-plane.